Not able to upsert in Chroma DB
I've been trying to upsert my dataset to Chroma DB but each time the code just terminates with upserting.
collection = client.get_or_create_collection('data',embedding_function=MiniLML6V2EmbeddingFunction())
    print("Upserting")
    try:
        collection.upsert(
            ids=idss,
            documents=docs
        )
        print("Upserting done")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Upserting failed: {e}")

Only upserting is getting printed and then the program stops.
Expecting upserting to be done
